# how to parse XML to get the data in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have an xml file and I want to the write the information on to the csv file.

I am trying to parse the xml to get the fields and the data and write onto a csv file. So  far I have been able to parse the data to get the information in relation to 
'title' and 'id' under node 'entry' but I am trying to parse the data under node '', 'id' information.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <feed xml:base="http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.giooglt.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
     <title type="text">Partners</title>
     <id>http://googlre.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners</id>
     <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
    < link rel="self" title="Partners" href="Partners" />
      <entry>
    <id>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555')</id>
   <title type="text">M55p; Co</title>
   <summary type="text">cccc is a Certified Partner, reseller, and implementer of 
   Key industries we work with include:
    •   Financial services
     •   Professional services
     •   Media / publishing


    By focusing on mid-market to enterprise clients, 
 </summary>
   <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
   <updated>2013-11-22T15:00:46-08:00</updated>
    <author>
    <name>google chrome</name>
    <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
    <email>retee@gmail.com</email>
   </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4255')" />
   <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Links" href="Partners('4559')/Links">
   <m:inline>
     <feed>
   <title type="text">Links</title>
  <id>http://google.com/('429')/Links</id>
  <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4ff')/Links" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://ryryr.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('ufufr')</id>
    <title type="text">
    </title>
    <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
    <category term="google.Commerce.ferrr.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.frrr.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Type>pgooglrpartnerpage</d:Type>
        <d:Description>google Partner Page</d:Description>
        <d:Url>http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet</d:Url>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  </m:inline>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555')</id>
   <title type="text">M55p; Co</title>
   <summary type="text">cccc is a Certified Partner, reseller, and implementer of 
   Key industries we work with include:
    •   Financial services
     •   Professional services
     •   Media / publishing


    By focusing on mid-market to enterprise clients, 
 </summary>
   <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
   <updated>2013-11-22T15:00:46-08:00</updated>
    <author>
    <name>google chrome</name>
    <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
    <email>retee@gmail.com</email>
   </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4255')" />
   <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Links" href="Partners('4559')/Links">
   <m:inline>
     <feed>
   <title type="text">Links</title>
  <id>http://google.com/('429')/Links</id>
  <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4ff')/Links" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://ryryr.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('ufufr')</id>
    <title type="text">
    </title>
    <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
    <category term="google.Commerce.ferrr.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.frrr.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Type>pgooglrpartnerpage</d:Type>
        <d:Description>google Partner Page</d:Description>
        <d:Url>http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet</d:Url>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  </m:inline>
  </entry>
  </feed>
```

The entries will be different but as one sees, I want to extract the information and write it onto a CSV file as -

Title,Id,PinpointId
//de:entry/de:title,//de:entry/de:title,//de:entry/de:link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id

for each and every entry.

The piece of code being used to get the information is :

```
     // Alternate Method for getting the Fields from the XML file
         XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
         xmlDocument.Load("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("de","http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");

        ParseXML(xmlDocument, xmlnm);

        Debug.WriteLine("\n---XML parsed---");

    }

    public static void ParseXML(XmlDocument xmlFile, XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm)
    {


        String path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/data.csv";
        var w = new StreamWriter(path); 



        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//de:entry", xmlnm);


        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            string titl = node["title"].InnerText;
            string ide = node["id"].InnerText;
            //string cty = node["link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id"].InnerText;
            Debug.WriteLine("Data :" + titl+"ID :"+ide);


        }

            }

     The output of the program is -

       Data :MIG & CoID :http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4295719419')
```

I am trying to parse the data like.
          string cty = node["link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id"].InnerText;

But the error generated.
          "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The xml has got multiple entries and in similar format. New to C# how to get the information and write it on to the CSV file.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First, your xml is not well formed.  It will need to be corrected.  Second, I am unsure exactly what node you are attempting to return with the query `"link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id"`

With that said, your `node["link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id"]` isn't valid, so it's not getting set to the XmlNode object you are expecting.  That's because an XmlNode item expects the name of a node, not an xpath query.  Use SelectSingleNode if you want to pass an xpath query.  Something like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string titl = node["title"].InnerText;
    string ide = node["id"].InnerText;
    string cty;
    var ctyNode = node.SelectSingleNode("link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id");
    if (ctyNode != null)
    {
        cty = ctyNode.InnerText
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Data :" + titl+"ID :"+ide);
}
```

Comment: However if there are multiple entries like - <entry>blblbl</entry><entry>blblbl</entry> then how will I get the data because the above modified step gives me back just data inside the first 'entry'

Comment: Right now, because your XML is not well formed, it is difficult to tell what your need is exactly.  The first place to start would be to fix your xml.

Comment: I think so the new edit will give you a better idea.

Comment: Please refer to the  new post.

Comment: Your XML is still not valid.  You can use an online xml validator to check it, such as http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ Any Xml parsing method needs to first have valid xml to parse.

Comment: I have got the answer and I am testing out XDocument to parse the XML, please check with another post for clarification = 
How to group elements of an xml file under the same root together in c#?