# How to group elements of an xml file under the same root together in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have an Xml file where I want to parse the 'title', 'id' and the 'description'(under properties) elements and want to write to a CSV file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.giooglt.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Partners</title>
  <id>http://googlre.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners</id>
  <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Partners" href="Partners" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555')</id>
    <title type="text">M55p; Co</title>
    <summary type="text">
      cccc is a Certified Partner, reseller, and implementer of
      Key industries we work with include:
      •   Financial services
      •   Professional services
      •   Media / publishing


      By focusing on mid-market to enterprise clients,
    </summary>
    <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
    <updated>2013-11-22T15:00:46-08:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name>google chrome</name>
      <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
      <email>retee@gmail.com</email>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4255')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Links" href="Partners('4559')/Links">
      <m:inline>
        <feed>
          <title type="text">Links</title>
          <id>http://google.com/('429')/Links</id>
          <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
          <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4ff')/Links" />
          <entry>
            <id>http://ryryr.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('ufufr')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
            <category term="google.Commerce.ferrr.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" sch="" eme="http://schemas.frrr.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>pgooglrpartnerpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>google Partner Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://googlet.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('tpartnerrfipage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-19T04:01:49Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('pinpointpartnerrfipage')" />
            <category term="google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>tpartnerrfipage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>RFI Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.mc_id=54545</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
        </feed>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45')</id>
    <title type="text">vfere</title>
    <summary type="text">
      cccc is a Certified Partner, reseller, and implementer of
      Key industries we work with include:
      •   Financial services
      •   Professional services
      •   Media / publishing


      By focusing on mid-market to enterprise clients,
    </summary>
    <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
    <updated>2013-11-22T15:00:46-08:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name>google chrome</name>
      <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
      <email>retee@gmail.com</email>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4255')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Links" href="Partners('4559')/Links" >
      <m:inline>
        <feed>
          <title type="text">Links</title>
          <id>http://google.com/('429')/Links</id>
          <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
          <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4ff')/Links" />
          <entry>
            <id>http://ryryr.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('ufufr')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
            <category term="google.Commerce.ferrr.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.frrr.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>pgooglrpartnerpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>google Partner Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://googlet.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('tpartnerrfipage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-19T04:01:49Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('pinpointpartnerrfipage')" />
            <category term="google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>tpartnerrfipage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>RFI Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.m</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
        </feed>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to group '/entry/title','/entry/id' and '/de:entry/link/m:inline/feed/entry/content/m:properties/Url'  and write to csv file. I can parse them all but cannot group  them together.

```
 M55p; Co,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555'),http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet
 M55p; Co,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555'),http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.mc_id=54545
  vfere,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45'),http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet
  vfere,http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45'),http: //pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&amp;wt.m
```

My code so far is

```
       // Alternate Method for getting the Fields from the XML file
         XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
         xmlDocument.Load("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("de","http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");

        ParseXML(xmlDocument, xmlnm);

        Debug.WriteLine("\n---XML parsed---");

        string xmlFileName = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml";
        XDocument customers = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);

        var queryResult = from c in customers.Descendants("entry").Attributes() select c.Name;
        foreach (var item in queryResult)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }      

    }



    public static void ParseXML(XmlDocument xmlFile, XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm)
    {

        List<string> id = new List<string>();
        List<string> title = new List<String>();
        List<String> city = new List<String>();
        String path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/data.csv";
        var w = new StreamWriter(path);
        //XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//ns:entry/ns:updated| //ns:entry/ns:published | //ns:entry/ns:id ", xmlnm);
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//de:entry/de:title  | //de:entry/de:link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id | //de:entry/de:link/m:inline/de:feed/de:entry/de:content/m:properties/d:Url | //de:entry/de:link/m:inline/de:feed/de:entry/de:content/m:properties/d:City | //de:entry/de:link/m:inline/de:feed/de:entry/de:content/m:properties/d:State | //de:entry/de:link/m:inline/de:feed/de:entry/de:content/m:properties/d:Country ", xmlnm);

        XmlNodeList nodes1 = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//de:entry", xmlnm);

        var line1 = string.Format("Field" + "," + "Data");
        w.WriteLine(line1);
        w.Flush();

        Debug.WriteLine(nodes1.Count);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(node.Name + " = " + node.InnerXml);
            var line = string.Format(node.Name + "," + node.InnerText);
            w.WriteLine(line);
            w.Flush();

        }




        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes1)
        {

           string titl = node["title"].InnerText;
           string ide = node["id"].InnerText;


                Debug.WriteLine("Data :" + titl + "ID :" + ide);
            }  

        }
```

I can group the 'title' and 'id' together but cannot read 'id' under 'properties' one at a time as specified in the example. Novice programmer, new to c#. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse XML to get the data in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201713/how-to-parse-xml-to-get-the-data-in-c)

Comment: The sample XML you posted wasn't valid. I tried to fix it based on the remaining text. Please make sure, I did it correctly.

Comment: @ Marcin : Yeah I did post it earlier as well but no reply, so this time I modified and put in the exact requirements. Any ideas?

Comment: @Damir : Thanks for the edit.Any ideas? I have almost every resources available online but have failed to parse the data  according to the requirement partially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code using `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument` which returns a strongly typed result according to your requirements:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml"))
{
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

    XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    XNamespace metadata = "http://schemas.giooglt.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
    XNamespace dataservices = "http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

    var result = xmlDoc.Root.Elements(atom + "entry")
        .Select(e => new {
            Title = e.Element(atom + "title").Value,
            Id = e.Element(atom + "id").Value,
            Urls = e.Elements(atom + "link")
                .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
                .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
                    .Element(atom + "feed")
                    .Elements(atom + "entry")
                    .Select(e1 => e1.Element(atom + "content")
                        .Element(metadata + "properties")
                        .Element(dataservices + "Url").Value))
            });

    foreach (var entry in result)
    {
        foreach (var url in entry.Urls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", entry.Title, entry.Id, url);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the structure of the anonymous class it returns:

```
class Result
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Urls { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the result for your sample:

```
Title = "M55p; Co"
Id = "http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555')"
Urls = 
{ 
    "http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&wt.mc_id=66ttet"
    "http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&wt.mc_id=54545"
}

Title = "vfere"
Id = "http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('45')"
Urls = 
{
    "http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&wt.mc_id=66ttet" 
    "http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4295719419&wt.m "
}
```

I'm not quite sure about the output CSV format you require, but I guess you should be able to create it yourself from this result.

EDIT: I included a simple dump to the console for your convenience, which resembles your sample output from the question.

Comment: Wonderful, I thank you so much.I was stuck for the most part.

Comment: I did look into XDocument, but I was not quite sure of the result. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: How to get the values of Urls for display? The results have worked for me.

Comment: How to use anonymous class to display the results

Comment: how to get the values of Url? I can not figure out the way to get the value.

Comment: @ Damir : How to get each values as an array as the way it is shown in your output. I am not getting how to get the desired result.I have also tried changing to .Element(dataservices + "Url").Elements().Select(url => url.Value))) but with no luck

Comment: @user3199528 I included a sample printout to the console. Hope it helps.

Comment: :Thanks for your help. It has not yet solved my problem, but has made me aware of such method.Actually the xml is bit different and I will post the full xml.

Comment: @user3199528 Ok, feel free to let me know when you post it and I'll take a look at it.